# Duplicate a row based in a column that has 2 values in spark sql

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a temporary view that looks like this.

```
ID   Activity
1    Yes           
2    Yes
3    No
4    Yes
```

What I want is to duplicate a row by adding an 'All' value to Activity

Expecting result would be:

```
ID   Activity
1    Yes           
2    Yes
3    No
4    Yes
1    All
2    All
3    All
4    All
```

I tried to create it through Zeppelin, but I am not able to update a view.

Is there any way to do it please ?

I can only use SQL unfortunately

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union`

```
select Id, Activity
from view

union all

select Id, 'All'
from view
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how should I do if I have a lot of columns please ? something like 100

Comment: Union requires the column in both queries to match by number and data type; you can include literal values eg *null* as a placeholder if for example to have 9 columns in the first query and 10 in the second.